# How do I tell SimpleSchema to update the current Meteor.user?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using the accounts-ui and autoform packages.  When the user is logged in there is a form to complete a basic user profile.

I'm getting this returned from SimpleSchema:

```
SimpleSchema invalid keys for "signupForm" context: [Object { name="_id", type="required", value=null}, Object { name="email", type="required", value=null}, Object { name="createdAt", type="required", value=null}]
```

The _id should just be the Meteor.userId() and the email should already be available in the user object, createdAt doesn't appear in the form anywhere.

How do I tell SimpleSchema that the _id should be the Meteor.userId(), the email should be the value already stored in the Meteor.user and the createdAt value should be the current time on the server?

This is my schema:

```
    Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female']
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
    },
    pinCode: {
        type: Number,
        min: 7,
        max: 7
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        min: 9,
        max: 10
    }
});


    Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: false
    }
});
SimpleSchema.debug = true;
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

These are the relevant helpers:

```
Template.signupForm.helpers({
  users: function () {
   return Meteor.users;
  },
  userSchema: function () {
   return Schema.User;
  }
});



Template.signupForm.editingDoc = function () {
 return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()});
};
```

My template:

```
<template name="signupForm">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{#autoForm collection=users schema=userSchema id="signupForm" type="insert"}}
    <fieldset>
      {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
   {{/autoForm}}
  </div>
</template>
```

I don't see anything in the SimpleSchema documentation that explains this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is explained in the collection2 docs, here:
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2/#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers